# Does recent macos have TTYs enabled? If not, is it possible to enable?

Tags: macos, big-sur, apple-silicon

On most Linux distributions, you have the ability to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open TTY1.

Does macOS have this ability? Is there a way to enable it?

If macOS freezes, it could be quite handy to be able to switch over to a TTY to enable one to execute a command or two to fix things.

If it matters, I am using a MacBook Air M1.

There is an answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18642325/606723) suggesting that you can use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, but that doesn't seem to work for me. It is also from 2009, so it could very well be out-of-date information.

> Only one TTY (TTY1) is available in OSX.
> To enable tty use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: If *macOS* freezes, you wouldn't be able to switch to another console (which would also be managed by macOS) anyway.

Comment: It depends on what part of macOS 'freezes'. It's quite common to use this in linux to kill an offending process. I recently had a similar problem in macos, where the cursor was still working and spinning. Leaving me to believe that *if* there was an option to open a TTY, it may have been assistive. Or at least would allow me to restart the device more gracefull.

Answer (score 8):

macOS boots into the graphical environment directly, there is no underlaying TTY from which the GUI is started (unlike Linux which boots into text mode from where you start X11 or whatever graphical environment you use).

You can enable ssh logins and then try to log in via ssh if the GUI freezes. This obviously requires access to a second device though.

Comment: Support for a text-only console is there, since that's what you get if you boot into single-user mode (Cmd+S on startup). It remains unclear if such a thing is accessible from an already booted machine.

Comment: I know; my point is that the ability to produce a console exists in the OS. It seems that it is only *accessible* via single-user mode, though. That would be something that has changed from earlier versions of OS X, which the linked question suggests supported Linux-like switching to *a* console, if not multiple ones.

Comment: I'm not saying that booting into single-user mode is what the user wants. I'm saying that the OS appears to lack a way to provide access to a console *except* by booting into single-user mode.

Answer (score 1):

nohillside is correct that no equivalent to "Ctrl+Alt+Fn" exists on the Mac.  The GUI implementation is not the same, although MacOS *does* have the ability to run XWindows/XOrg based applications through the use of an appropriate built-in tool.